# How to mock the npm module that exports the default and the object

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have created a library that exports the default object that includes a few utility functions. Along with default, I have also exported a couple of enums. Here is how my exports look like in the root file of the library

```
exports.default = new _oAuth2.default();
var OAUTH_LOG_LEVELS = exports.LOG_LEVELS = {DEBUG: 10, WARN: 20};
var OAUTH_VERSIONS = exports.VERSIONS = {V1: '1.0', v2: '2.0'}
```

In my react app I am importing and using the values this like

```
import lib1, {VERSIONS, LOG_LEVELS} from 'mylib';

lib1.init({
  verion: VERSIONS.V1,
})
```

Everything is working fine in the app. Now, I want to add a unit test in the app using Jest, I tried to mock the library. Here is my mock

```
jest.mock('myLib', () => ({
  init: jest.fn(),
}));
```

Now, my question is, how to mock the library to include the enums along with defaults? I tried multiple ways but did not succeed. Without that, I cannot use the enums exposed by the library. When I try to use that, the unit test is throwing an error that VERSIONS is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jest.requireActual` to get the actual exported values and override just the ones you need to.

```
jest.mock('myLib', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('myLib'),
  init: jest.fn(),
}));
```

You might need something like `...jest.requireActual('myLib').default` instead depending on how you have your exports set up.

Answer (score 0):

After digging more into Jest documentation, I found a way to explicitly mock the library as an esModule. I updated my mock to

```
jest.mock('myLib', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: {
    init: jest.fn(),
  },
  VERSIONS: {V1: '1.0'},
}));
```

This fixed my problem.